# Contraction of blow up of $\mathbf{P}^n$ at a linear subspace

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $L=\mathbf{P}^m\subset\mathbf{P}^n$ be a linear subspace with $1\leq m\leq n-2$, say defined by $x_{m+1}=\ldots=x_n=0$. Let the blow up $X$ of $\mathbf{P}^n$ with center $L$. The exceptional divisor is of the form $E=\mathbf{P}^m\times\mathbf{P}^{n-m-1}$. Then the blow up morphism contracts second component. Alternatively,by Fujiki-Nakano criterion (Remark 11.10 in Fourier Mukai by Huybrechts), there is a morphism
$$f:X\to Y$$
which is a blow up of $\mathbf{P}^{n-m-1}\subset Y$ with exceptional divisor $E$ and whose retraction to $E$ is the contraction of the first component
$$\pi':\mathbf{P}^m\times\mathbf{P}^{n-m-1}\to \mathbf{P}^{n-m-1}$$

My question is: Is $f$ the blow up of $\mathbf{P}^n$ with center $x_0=\ldots=x_m=0$? If not, what does $Y$ look like?

Answer (score 1):

The second contraction is not birational. In fact, it is a $\mathbb{P}^{m+1}$-bundle over $\mathbb{P}^{n-m-1}$ induced by the linear projection $\mathbb{P}^n \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-m+1}$ out of $\mathbb{P}^m$.

Comment: Hi Sasha, sorry if my original question is not clear. I meant $f$ to be the blow up morphism resulting from Fujiki-Nakano criterion. I have edited the question.

Comment: @RustQ: The Picard number of $X$ is 2, so there are just two extremal contractions of $X$ --- one gives back $\mathbb{P}^n$, the other is the Mori fiber space $X \to \mathbb{P}^{n-m+1}$. No other contractions exist.